# Incorrect render order in google chrome with nested css transforms

Tags: google-chrome, css-transforms

In Google Chrome when rotating certain ancestor elements in my application, some children 'disappear' by rendering behind the background of their immediate parent.

It seems to be related to whether the compositor decides to create a new layer. I have done some research on stacking contents, and compositor layers but have been unable to determine what is causing this issue.

Below is a minimal reproduction.

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; transform: rotate(10deg);">
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: green; will-change: top; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    Text that is visible
    <div style="display: inline-block; transform: translateX(0px);">
      Text that is hidden
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The string "Text that is hidden" should actually appear but for some reason does not in Google Chrome. This does not seem to affect Edge or Firefox.

Disabling almost any of the styles in this example will fix the problem but I am trying to get to the bottom of the root cause.

Curiously at certain rotations the issue disappears e.g. rotate(5deg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me why this works, but adding isolation: isolate to the middle div resolves this. If anyone can explain why this works I will accept your answer instead.

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; transform: rotate(10deg);">
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: green; will-change: top; overflow: hidden; position: relative; isolation: isolate">
    Text that is visible
    <div style="display: inline-block; transform: translateX(0px);">
      Text that is hidden
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```